# Can't assign text value to a variable from JQuery element in event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick, jquery-events

This is some event handling for a list of items in my dom. 
Using event delegation, the click handler is on the parent container

```
$( "#list" ).on( "click", "a", (event) => {

            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();

            let text = $(this).parent().children().last().text();

            // The following HAS content (seen in the dev tools debugger !!!!)
            // $(this).parent().children().last().text() 

            // But the text variable gets No content - WHY ?
            // "" is printed....
            console.log(text);   
        });
```

Any ideas? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the html dom please ?

Comment: The html is being generated dynamically at run time. The value that I see for the ```$(this).....``` is CORRECT.  I just don't see it in the 'text' variable a line after...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use arrow function and `this` in arrow function is `window` in browser.

```
$( "#list" ).on( "click", "a", function (event)  {

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    let text = $(this).parent().children().last().text();

    debugger
    console.log(text);   
});
```